# Using AJAX to launch PHP without reloading page

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, post

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form class="clearfix" method="POST">
 <input name="name" type="textbox" placeholder="Name:">
 <input name="email" type="textbox" placeholder="Email:">
 <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Which launches a PHP script (which works) but re-directs the user to the empty page containing the PHP (ie. goes to mywebpage.com/send_mail.php). Using AJAX, how can I launch the PHP script in the background without re-loading the page?

I have the following AJAX request but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#msg").val()
 };

 $.ajax({
    url: '../send_mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('Email Sent');
    }
 });
});
```

Any assistance as to why it's not working? At the moment, all it does (when hitting submit) is go straight to the PHP page and seems to ignore the AJAX

Comment: First change `url: ../send_mail.php,` to `url: '../send_mail.php,'` what is error you're facing?

Comment: @Alok Please see my edit - there is no error, the page just reloads and doesn't send the email

Comment: `#submit` is not there

Comment: @Alok Infact no, I tell a lie, the page ignores the AJAX and just goes straight to 'page.com/send_mail.php'

Comment: @Chay22 I added an id to the submit button but still not working

Comment: Try to listening to `submit` event rather than `click`. Or change the button type to `button` as my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting reload because it's a `submit` button and that is added inside `form` so it's submitting the form on click without waiting for **AJAX** to get submitted.

You can use [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) jQuery method to stop the page redirect. Like this,

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#msg").val()
 };

 $.ajax({
    url: '../send_mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('Email Sent');
    }
 });
});
```

> When **preventDefault();** method is called, the default action of the
>   event will not be triggered.

You've also missed quotes to specify **URL** in **.ajax()**.

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpft17y/

Comment: Tried this but still ignoring the AJAX. Do I still need to keep `method="POST" action="send_mail.php"` on the html form attributes?

Comment: Yeah it's still getting refreshed ? Or you're facing any other issue?

Comment: Yep, it seems like the page is still ignoring the AJAX and doing straight to the php page

Comment: @blueprintChris Remove the `action` attribute i.e. `action="send_mail.php"`  from your `form` element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpft17y/ check this, it's shouldn't get refreshed if you've placed preventDefault() correctly.

Comment: I removed the action attribute and now all its doing is refreshing the page - the PHP isn't being run because I am no longer receiving the email upon hitting submit

Comment: @blueprintChris open up the console in inspect element. Do you see any error ? Have you included jQuery library correctly?

Comment: @Alok just checked console and it says $ is not defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116260/discussion-between-alok-and-blueprintchris).

Answer (score 0):

Use input type as button `type = "button"` instead of submit.

Comment: A link specifying the definition from MDN might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button#attr-type